# How to invoke Oracle's password change window from VBA

Tags: oracle, vba, passwords

I have an Access 2010 application using Oracle as a back end database. The application uses ODBC to connect to the database using Oracle user credentials.

When new users are added, the DBA sets an initial password that is expired, so the user must change it the first time they log in. I need to provide a password change facility within the application. I read somewhere that this line:

```
Set db = OpenDatabase("", False, True, "ODBC;DSN=" & myDSN & ";UID=" & userName & ";PWD=" & oldPwd)
```

shows the standard Oracle's password change window, which would be more than acceptable for my purposes. Now, sometimes this thing works exactly as I said, but sometimes it doesn't: it produces no error and no problem at all - it's just as if it is not executed at all. The code simply goes on past it.

Can anyone tell me why this happens, or if there's a better way to let the users change their passwords?